# RxJS Observable Share startWith() state in merge()

Tags: rxjs, observable, recompose

How can I share the `startWith(false)` state between the 3 streams? I tried using `withLatestFrom()` but got some weird errors for the value.

```jsx
const Home = componentFromStream(prop$ => {
  const { handler: toggleHandler, stream: toggle$ } = createEventHandler();
  const { handler: showHandler, stream: show$ } = createEventHandler();
  const { handler: hideHandler, stream: hide$ } = createEventHandler();

  const modal$ = merge(
    toggle$.pipe(
      startWith(false),
      map(() => prev => !prev),
      scan((state, changeState: any) => changeState(state))
    ),
    show$.pipe(
      startWith(false),
      map(() => prev => true),
      scan((state, changeState: any) => changeState(state))
    ),
    hide$.pipe(
      startWith(false),
      map(() => prev => false),
      scan((state, changeState: any) => changeState(state))
    )
  );

  return combineLatest(prop$, modal$).pipe(
    map(([props, modal]) => {
      console.log(modal);
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={toggleHandler}>Toggle</button>
          <button onClick={showHandler}>Show</button>
          <button onClick={hideHandler}>Hide</button>
          <h1>{modal ? 'Visible' : 'Hidden'}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    })
  );
});
```

In the example, the `toggle` doesn't respect the current value of `show` or `hide`, but only of its own latest value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rxjs6-recompose

Comment: `merge` subscribes to all source Observables at the same time so all three sources will emit `startWith(false)` immediately which is not what you want I guess?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you will need to manage state a bit differently, something similar to what people do in redux. Take a look at example:

```js
const { of, merge, fromEvent } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { map, scan } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const toggle$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('toggle'), 'click');
const show$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('show'), 'click');
const hide$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('hide'), 'click');

const reduce = (state, change) => change(state);

const initialState = false;
const state$ = merge(
  of(e => e),
  toggle$.pipe(map(e => state => !state)),
  show$.pipe(map(e => state => true)),
  hide$.pipe(map(e => state => false)),
).pipe(
  scan(reduce, initialState),
);

state$.subscribe(e => console.log('state: ', e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>


<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
```

To better understand how it works, take a look at [Creating applications](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/tutorial/applications.md) article from rxjs documentation

Comment: This is imho not correct solution. First it doesn't emit anything until one of observables emits. Second and most importantly toggle will work only with last state of toggle button. Therefore it doesn't toggle after you change the value with show/hide button.

Comment: @MartinNuc the toggle seems to consider the state of hide/show when I tested this out

Comment: I think semantically using `startWith()` to set the value is more intuitive than setting the initial value in `scan()`

Answer (score 0):

First having `startWith` on all those observables means they will all emit at the beginning false. Which is like you pushed all those buttons at once.

I think you should  try to achieve different behaviour. Using `startWith` you want to set the initial state of the `modal` property, right? Therefore it should come after merging those stream together.

To toggle the value you need two things:

1. place where to store the state (usually accumulator of `scan`)
2. differentiate those button presses. You have three buttons therefore you need three values.

This is my approach:

```
 const modal$ = merge(
    show$.pipe(mapTo(true)),
    hide$.pipe(mapTo(false)),
    toggle$.pipe(mapTo(null))
  ).pipe(
    startWith(false),
    scan((acc, curr) => {
      if (curr === null) {
        return !acc;
      } else {
        return curr;
      }
    })
  );
```

Show button always emits `true`, hide button emits `false` and toggle button emits `null`. I merge them together and we want to start with `false`. Next there is `scan` which holds the state in accumulator.

When `null` comes it returns negated state. When `true` or `false` comes it returns it - that way it sets the new state regardless the previous value.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this! The answer works, but moving the toggle logic into scan seems a bit more difficult to read, the other approach seems more intuitive.

Comment: No problem. Passing a function is very elegant solution which didnt come up to my mind. One always learns something new :-)

Answer (score 0):

I took everyone's approach & came up with this. It keeps the toggle() logic inside the map function, & uses startWith() to set the value.

```js
  const modal$ = merge(
    toggle$.pipe(
      map(() => prev => !prev),
    ),
    show$.pipe(
      map(() => prev => true),
    ),
    hide$.pipe(
      map(() => prev => false),
    )
  ).pipe(
    startWith(false),
    scan((state, change) => change(state)),
  );
```